# How can I shorten this code (for loop help)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
string1 = str(input("Type a word"))
for i in range(len(string1)):
    print(string1[-1+i], end= "")
print('')
for i in range(len(string1)):
    print (string1[-2+i] , end= "")
print('')
for i in range(len(string1)):
    print (string1[-3+i] , end= "")
print('')
for i in range(len(string1)):
    print (string1[-4+i] , end= "")
print('')
for i in range(len(string1)):
    print (string1[-5+i] , end= "")
```

How can I shorten this code? It seems highly inefficient, and I think it could be much much shorter. Also the amount of letters is limited because you have to add another loop for an additional letter.
Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I want the first letter to move to the left of the word.
For example: Borrow.
The first loop would be Borrow
The second
wBorro
the third:
owBorr
And  so on

Answer (score 2):

Only one loop.

```py
string1 = str(input("Type a word"))
for i in range(1,len(string1)+1):
    print(string1[-i:] + string1[:-i])
```

Answer (score 0):

To rotate a string slice of the last letter and put it in the front:

`s = s[-1] + s[:-1]`

Example:

```
word = "Example"

# we do not care about the letters, just want to loop one time for each letter
for _ in word:
    print(word)
    word = word[-1] + word[:-1]
```

Output:

```
Example
eExampl
leExamp
pleExam
mpleExa
ampleEx
xampleE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = str(input("Type a word"))
for i in range(1,len(a)):
    print(a[-i:]+a[:-i])
```

Answer (score -2):

Python's [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) function can be used to generate the index starting numbers that you're using (-1, -2, etc.).

It accepts a `step` parameter that can be used to count backwards:

```
string1 = str(input("Type a word"))

for n in range(-1, -6, -1):
  for i in range(len(string1)):
    print(string1[n+i], end= "")
  print('')
```